# java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod objects are leaked in the memory in Android

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I got this when I was checking the memory leak by LeakCanary, but there is no info on it:

[image: The screenshot taken from LeakCanary]

And when I tried to make a dump in Android Studio Memory Monitor, I found this:

[image: the screenshot taken from Memory Monitor]

Could anyone please give some hint on what the "*.ArtMethod" class is?

Answer (score 2):

Just a update that I have solved the problem. What I found is, if I use PublisherAdView to load an AdRequest, this memory leak happens.

Then I tried to use the ApplicationContext to be the context used when constructing the PublisherAdView (it was using the Activity as context before), the memory leak disappears.

By the way, I have tried to do the things as following:

```
adViewsContainer.removeAllViews();
adView.setAdListener(null);
adView.onDestroy();
adView = null;
```

But the memory leak is still there when I was using the Activity as Context.